# Hitting "enter" does not post form in IE8

Tags: php, html, forms, submit, form-submit

I'm using PHP to pass a login form when required, and here is the code:

```
$htmlForm = '<form id="frmlogin">'.'<label>';
switch(LOGIN_METHOD)
{
    case 'both':
        $htmlForm .= $ACL_LANG['USERNAME'].'/'.$ACL_LANG['EMAIL'];
        break;
    case 'email':
        $htmlForm .= $ACL_LANG['EMAIL'];
        break;
    default:
        $htmlForm .= $ACL_LANG['USERNAME'];
        break;
}                       

$htmlForm .= ':</label>'.
             '<input type="text" name="u" id="u" class="textfield" />'.
             '<label>'.$ACL_LANG['PASSWORD'].'</label>'.
             '<input type="password" name="p" id="p" class="textfield" />'.
             '<center><input type="submit" name="btn" id="btn" class="buttonfield" value="Sign in to extranet" /></center>'.
             '</form>';

return $htmlForm;
```

The problem is, is that when the user hits enter in IE8, the form does not submit, and the user is forced to hit the submit button.

How do I rectify this?

Comment: It's even worse: As of jQuery 1.4, my listener bound to the form's `submit` event gets run, but even though it returns true, the submit doesn't happen! This is disastrous because that listener then disables the form to prevent duplicate submission, so IE users who hit enter are then unable to submit at all. My solution is that for IE users, if they press enter in a form input, I catch that and return false - do nothing. They **must** click to submit. (Messing with visibility isn't an option here, since the form is loaded via AJAX.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is a real problem and you can't find another solution you can always do an `onkeypress` event for the form and check if the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key was pressed.

EDIT:
Here's the correct code according to Machine's answer:

```
$htmlForm .= ':<form><label>'.$ACL_LANG['USERNAME'].'</label>'.
                                     '<input type="text" name="u" id="u" class="textfield" />'.
                                     '<label>'.$ACL_LANG['PASSWORD'].'</label>'.
                                     '<input type="password" name="p" id="p" class="textfield" />'.
                                     '<center><input type="submit" name="btn" id="btn" class="buttonfield" value="Sign in to extranet" /></center>'.
                                     '</form>';
```

EDIT 2:
Your HTML is valid.
Try [this](http://jennifermadden.com/javascript/stringEnterKeyDetector.html):

```
function checkEnter(e) { //e is event object passed from function invocation
    var characterCode //literal character code will be stored in this variable

    if (e && e.which) { //if which property of event object is supported (NN4)
        e = e
        characterCode = e.which //character code is contained in NN4's which property
    }
    else {
        e = event
        characterCode = e.keyCode //character code is contained in IE's keyCode property
    }

    if (characterCode == 13) { //if generated character code is equal to ascii 13 (if enter key)
        document.forms[0].submit() //submit the form
        return false
    }
    else {
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: type in first row .

is: <labl>
should be: <label>

Comment: Could you just revise the code from the full piece of code for that section to which I've added the full code?

Comment: It seems that your html is valid.
Take a look at the answer now.

Comment: See the comment of @infinity for the real solution.

Answer (score 13):

Also watch out for this fun fun bug:

I've learned the hard way that if your form is `display:none` at page load, even if you show it later with Javascript, IE8 still won't submit on enter.
However, if it's not hidden at page load, and you set it to `display:none` after, like onDOMReady, then it works! WTF

More details and workaround here: http://www.thefutureoftheweb.com/blog/submit-a-form-in-ie-with-enter

Comment: Thanks! I did not know about this! IE7 **does** work if the form is `display:none` and IE8 does not....

Answer (score 7):

### Simulate a click

Here's how I do it in jQuery.

```
// Recreating normal browser behavior in Javascript. Thank you, Microsoft.
jQuery.fn.handle_enter_keypress = function() {
  if ($.browser.msie){
    $(this).find('input').keypress(function(e){
      // If the key pressed was enter
      if (e.which == '13') {
        $(this).closest('form')
        .find('button[type=submit],input[type=submit]')
        .filter(':first').click();
      }
    });
  }
}

$('form').handle_enter_keypress();
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a link in Microsoft on it which might shed some light for you.

Taking a quick read of the link it might actually be considered a bug submitting the form by the Enter Key, which I presume would of been fixed by Microsoft for IE8.

[IE anomaly when using the enter key to submit a form](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/collaborate/connect-redirect?FeedbackID=362726)

Edit:

This has now been removed but another [link](https://www.gtalbot.org/BrowserBugsSection/MSIE8Bugs/not-submitting-submit-value.html) covering it again (bottom of page) which [defined it and explaining the bug in IE Blog on December 18th 2008](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ie/ie-december-out-of-band-release).

Comment: Good spot its now been removed. I've managed to find some other links which reference it but as its been resolved they have removed it.

Answer (score 3):

Do you have an opening form tag that was just omitted from your code snippet?

Answer (score 1):

The `action` attribute on the `form` element is required by the HTML spec. Maybe it'll work better.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reproduce this as well with an action and method. Stripped out all other code on the page and it still gets produced. However, I have seen forms work in IE8 with action=""