# IE Not submitting my form on enter press of enter key?

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

I have coded custom form validation. validation is working fine all browser but when I am pressing enter key IE is not submitting from if user entered correct data... on click of button its submitting form. I have tried to debug it , its returning true after validation but not submiting form...

```
(function($){
$.fn.securityFramework = function() {
    var form = $(this);
    var $submitBtn = $('input.sf-submit');

    var errorClass = "error";
    var passClass = "pass";
    var MandatoryClass = "mandatory";
    //var $securityQuestions = $('.securityQuestions');

    // used in form submission
    var submitOK = false;
    var currentPWResult = true;
    var tcResult = true;

    //check username length
    var $userName = $('#userName',form);

    // create empty warning spans to stop focus issues in IE
    //displayResult($('input[type=text]', form), "","");
    //displayResult($('input[type=password]', form), "","");

    /* Registration form checks */
    // check user name for length and invaid characters
    $userName.keyup(function() {
        var userResult = minLength(6, $userName.val().length);
        var userNameResult =  validUserName($userName.val());
        if ( $(this).val() != "" ) {

            if ( userResult || userNameResult ) {
                if(userResult) {
                    //displayResult($(this), 'Please choose a longer username', errorClass);
                    $(this).focus();
                } 

                if(userNameResult) {
                    //displayResult($(this), 'Your username contains invalid characters', errorClass);
                    $(this).focus();
                }
            } else {
                //displayResult($(this), '', passClass);
                $(this).focus();
            }
        }
    });


    // check that all form text inputs are not empty
    $('input[type=text]:not(input.email)', this).blur(function() {
        $(this).each(function(index, value) {
            if( isEmptyString($(this)) ) {
                var message = checkManitoryMessage($(this));
                //displayResult($(this), message, MandatoryClass);
            } else {
                // remove mandatory class
                if ( $(this).siblings().hasClass('mandatory') ) {
                    $(this).siblings().remove();
                }
            }
        });
    });

    $('input[type=password]:not(input.password)', this).blur(function() {
        $(this).each(function(index, value) {
            if( isEmptyString($(this)) ) {
                var message = checkManitoryMessage($(this));
                //displayResult($(this), message, MandatoryClass);
            } else {
                // remove mandatory class
                if ( $(this).siblings().hasClass('mandatory') ) {
                    $(this).siblings().remove();
                }
            }
        });
    });


    // check validation on form submission
    form.submit(function(e) {
        // trigger checks for empty fields
        $('input[type=password]', form).trigger('blur');
        $('input[type=text]', form).trigger('blur');

        submitCheck();
        if(submitOK ) {
            alert("true");
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }); 


    // generic testing functions
    function emailVal(emailAddress) {
        emailAddress = emailAddress.toLowerCase();
        var pattern = new RegExp(/^[a-z0-9_\+-]+(\.[a-z0-9_\+-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*\.([a-z]{2,4})$/);
        return pattern.test(emailAddress);
    }

    // check for empty string
    function isEmptyString(jQueryObj) {
        return ( jQueryObj.val() == "");
    }

    // check username for invalid characters ("!£$%?/@)
    function validUserName(name) {
        var pattern = new RegExp(/["\u00A3!\$%\?/@]/);
        return pattern.test(name);
    }

    // check string length against a value
    function minLength(minLength, string) {
        return((string+1) <= minLength);

    }

    // check that two strings match
    function checkStringsMatch(string1, string2){
        // console.log('str1: ' + string1 + ' str2: ' + string2);
        return(string1 == string2);
    }
    // check for password validation
    function checkPasswordValidation(passwordObj){
        password=passwordObj.val();
        var pattern = new RegExp(/^.*(?=.{8,})(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*\d).*$/);
        return pattern.test(password);
    }

    // check password strength
    function checkPwStrength() {
        var pwStrength = $('#strengthWidget').attr('class');
        // check class for password classification
        if(pwStrength == 'pw-weak') {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    // generic display error and confirm message function
    function displayResult(selector, message, className) {
        // check to see if input has a wrapper span to hold message
        if(selector.parent().hasClass('wrapper')) {
            // has wrapper, remove message contained
            selector.parent().children('span').remove();
        } else {
            // no wrapper, add one to append message to
            selector.wrap('<span class="wrapper"></span>');
        }
        selector.parent().append('<span class="' + className + '">' + message + '</span>');
    }

    // checks to see if any errors on page, if none found enable submission
    function submitCheck() {
        var $errorsExist = $('.error', form);
        var $mandErrorsExist = $('.mandatory', form);
        var $highlightErrorsExist = $('.highlightError', form);
        // console.log($highlightErrorsExist.length);
        // console.log('$errorsExist.length: ' + $errorsExist.length);
        // console.log('$mandErrorsExist.length: ' + $mandErrorsExist.length);

        if ($errorsExist.length || $mandErrorsExist.length || $highlightErrorsExist.length ) {
            submitOK = false;
        } else {
            submitOK = true;
        }
        // console.log('submitOK = ' + submitOK );
    }

    function checkManitoryMessage($object) {
        var inputId = '';
        inputId = $object.attr('id');

        inputId = inputId.toLowerCase();
        if (inputId == undefined) {
            inputId = 'Manditory Field';
        } else {
            inputId = sfErrors[inputId];
        }
        return inputId;
    }

    return form;
}; // end of plugin
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: is it the only submit button on the page? If not, is it the first to appear in the order of the source code? By default, hitting enter will submit the first submit button found on the page. If this is the only one then you might need to create another function to listen for the enter key and the form will then be submitted, only problem is a user may hit enter when they finish with a particular field etc and the form tries to submit when that's not what they want to do but I suppose your validation won't submit the form anyway so there shouldn't be any adverse effects to doing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

```
$("form input").keypress(function (e) {
   if(e.which === 13) {
      $("form").submit();
   }
});
```