# Enter key doesn't submit search

Tags: php, javascript, html, internet-explorer-9

When compatibility view is ON in IE9, does it recognise an enter if I type something in a test input and press the enter key?

I am asking this because when compatibility is off, when I press enter key, it submits the data in the test input, but do it when compatibility view is on and it does not submit the text input, it just like goes back to default, I have to press the `Search` button to submit the search .

The explain this it is easier to show a demo here: [demo](http://helios.hud.ac.uk/u0867587/Mobile_app/previousquestions.php?questioncontent=2)

Test the application in IE9 compatibility off or any other major browser and when you submit search with enter key then it submit search. But then test it with compatibility is on and it doesn't submit the search when using enter key.

Im not sure if this could be a php, javascript or html causing this so please comment to me where he issue can be and I will display my code in an update, this just saves me from posting whole code

Comment: What steps have you tried with troubleshooting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's a compatibility issue that exists in IE 7 and IE 8 as well. A similar question was asked here: [In IE8 enter key in a form does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427912/in-ie8-enter-key-in-a-form-does-not-work)

The suggested solution is to try making your submit button:

```
<button type="submit"...>
```

as opposed to

```
<input type="submit"...>
```

What seems to be happening is that instead of making a GET request to:

http://helios.hud.ac.uk/u0867587/Mobile_app/previousquestions.php?questioncontent=test&searchQuestion=Search

It's making one to:

http://helios.hud.ac.uk/u0867587/Mobile_app/previousquestions.php?questioncontent=test