# Hitting "enter" button does not submit form in IE8

Tags: jquery, forms, internet-explorer-8

In our organization we're still using the IE8 standard. On one of our web-based applications, we noticed we could not submit forms via the `Enter` key. After searching the web, I stumbled across this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4629047/731052

While the jQuery solution does work, our users still get a "ding" whenever they press the `Enter` key. Is there a way to prevent this from happening? When I'm on sites like Google, I don't get any "dings" when I press enter. Thanks!

Comment: Could you show your relevant code?

Comment: Can you show please what exactly makes the 'ding!' right now? :)

Comment: Also, make sure you have all updates installed. There were a number of "security" patches to IE8 which actually fixed bugs.

Comment: I copied/pasted that code exactly as shown.

Comment: @MrOBrian this seems to be aimed at "their" users. If all of their users knew about security updates/patched they would probably upgrade to IE9 instead of using IE8.

Comment: @ejohansson except that IE8 is the highest you can go on XP, and many corporate computers still run XP. This is one problem I'm running into currently, and it's quite frustrating.

Comment: @MrOBrian I agree this is a big problem for a majority of the developer community. The thing is you cannot force an end-user to upgrade their browser especially in a corporate environment where things are highly controlled by the "IT-department". You either have to find a solution or cut your losses.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

use this

```
if (e.which == '13') {
    e.preventDefault();
   //then put your code
   }
```

Assuming you were using the code from the question that you have a link to

```
jQuery.fn.handle_enter_keypress = function() {
  if ($.browser.msie){
    $(this).find('input').keypress(function(e){
      // If the key pressed was enter
      if (e.which == '13') {
        $(this).closest('form')
        .find('button[type=submit],input[type=submit]')
        .filter(':first').click();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm going off the assumption you're using code from the link to the other question you have a link to

Comment: Yes, I was using the exact code--copy/paste. Thanks for this--it works like a charm!